# Echoing php in h2

Tags: php, css, styles, call

Im echoing a php statement within a div and h2. The statement calls a username from a database. However, the name that is called, is forced one line under the welcome. How do i keep the two words on the same line?

```
<div id="teaser">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div class="box">
            <h2>Welcome</h2> 
    <?php
  session_start ();
   if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
echo "<h2>".$_SESSION['username']."!</h2>";
     else
die("You must be logged in!");
     ?>
```

Any suggestions to make them stay on the same line? The div isnt too small or any either.

Comment: You are adding two h2 tags, so there are two solutions, display the message on the same tag or fix it with css displaying inline.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h2>Welcome <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
   echo 'You must be logged in';
}
?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css to make your `<h2>` an inline element (instead of block):

```css
#teaser h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Or modify your PHP to echo the text within the `<h2>`:

```
<div id="teaser"> 
    <div class="wrap"> 
        <div id="image"></div> 
        <div class="box"> 
            <h2>Welcome  
    <?php 
  session_start (); 
   if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
echo $_SESSION['username']."!"; 
     else 
die("You must be logged in!"); 
     ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Headers are block elements, so they will take a line.

You should change its display to inline by adding the attribute style="display: inline;" or edit the css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the closing `</h2>` after "welcome" and the opening `<h2>` in the echo.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advice you re-organize your code in such way:

```
<?php 
  $user_name = '';
  session_start ();
  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $user_name = $_SESSION['username'];
  }     
  else{
        $user_name = "- You must be logged in!";
  }     
?>


<div id="teaser">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div class="box">
            <h2>Welcome <?php echo $user_name; ?></h2> 
          </div>
```

Separating PHP and HTML Code makes it more easy to work with code and find possible errors.
When page is such simple it seems not important, but in more complex projects mixing code can make it very heavily readable and hard to support :-(

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like to embed PHP conditionals into single html lines, rather I prefer to localize conditional variables at the top of my html files into single vars. Then when I add them to the html, it results in easier to read code. Like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Ternary op, if username is available, use it, otherwise default to null
$userMessage = 'Welcome' . ((isset($_SESSION['username'])) ? ' ' . $_SESSION['username'] : null);
?>

<div id="teaser">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div class="box">
            <h2><?php echo $userMessage ?></h2>
```

Or if you want to get a bit more complicated:

```
<?php session_start() ?>

<div id="teaser">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="image"></div>
        <div class="box">
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
            <h2>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?></h2> 
            <?php else: ?>
            <h2>Welcome stranger, click <a href="lilo.php">here</a> to login</h2>
            <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Any of the answers help at all? If so please accept accordingly.